# Is there a database of soccer match stats which include VAR calls?

Tags: football, statistics, video-review

I am wondering if there is a database compiling match/player stats for leagues (or maybe UEFA Champions League) which have VAR in place. I'm particularly interested in stats surrounding VAR itself, such as how many VAR calls were made per game, or at what time in the match VAR was used.

Comment: I don't think stats like that will be collected for public use from game officials and TV and other media won't be able to do so, since quite a few VAR decisions are made silently. Only overturned calls must be signaled by refs or when they want to watch a scene for themselves, so there's a chance to miss some calls.